# How to set a line width in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am doing following code to produce big size of line width.

```
doc.setLineWidth(400);
```

but not happen anything and the line still thin size after that.

This is my complete code

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

doc.line(30, 30, 560, 30); // horizontal line  

doc.setLineWidth(400);
```

How to set a line width correctly?

[image: Result and expectation]

Comment: Can you give an example of the **PDF** content please? Thank you.

Comment: please see again my question I am already add picture for detail

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you have to understand that at first you have to set the width value and then you can use it. And you do it on the wrong way: you set it after using.

**Correct example**

```js
function generatePDF()
{
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    pdf.setLineWidth(5.0); 
    pdf.line(30, 30, 560, 30);
    pdf.save('test.pdf');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onclick="generatePDF()">Generate PDF</button>
```

Comment: so, is this correct way to change size weight of jspdf line ?

pdf.setLineWidth(5.0); 

I am using very big number but, why do not happen anything?
doc.setLineWidth(400);

Comment: @Alimin. I wrote it already: you write it on wrong way like this: `pdf.line(30, 30, 560, 30); pdf.setLineWidth(5.0);` But correct way is: `pdf.setLineWidth(5.0); pdf.line(30, 30, 560, 30);`.

Comment: do you mean. setLineWidth at first and then create line ?

Comment: @Alimin. exactly! ;-)

Comment: How `pdf.line` value are set ? there are 4 params. would you care to explain that.

Comment: @Santosh, you could read about it in the [documentation](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#line), please. [Official jsPDF page](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)